# How to set input on chrome extension to text from dom?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get text from the web page on click into the input on my chrome extension.
Content script

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  let target = e.target
  let text = target.textContent || target.innerText;
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text }, function (response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
}, false);
```

and background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    document.getElementById("userinput").value = "My value";
    sendResponse({ farewell: request.text });
  }
);
```

My popup.html just has id of 'userinput' and i am getting `unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.` Error

Comment: Move onMessage listener to the popup script.

Comment: The background.js cannot access the DOM id userinput. What does the background.js console say. Normally the message port will close after time. I think because of an error